# Para que servem os valores padrões do CSS?

Tags: css

Quase todo comando CSS tem seu valor padrão, que já esta sendo empregado por padrão, mesmo que você não o use, por exemplo.

```
justify-content: flex-start;
```

Se você não escrever nada por padrão o elemento já vai ficar como `flex-start` então afinal para que servem os valores padrões, se eles já estão sendo empregados por padrão?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O padrão existe e está disponível por dois motivos principais:

1. Caso você aplique um novo estilo e precise voltar para o padrão para exceções a este estilo, ex:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
div.start {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Primeiro</span>
  <span>Segundo</span>
  <span>Terceiro</span>
</div>
<div class="start">
  <span>Primeiro</span>
  <span>Segundo</span>
  <span>Terceiro</span>
</div>
```

2. Quem aplica o padrão é o navegador, portanto se você não fizer uma definição terá que confiar que o navegador esteja aplicando os padrões corretamente. Caso queira garantir que seu layout fique o mais parecido possível em qualquer dispositivo / navegador, é interessante o uso da técnica de "reset.css", onde é aplicado definições padrões mesmo que estas já sejam contempladas pelo browser.

Answer (score 2):

Vou te dar um exemplo simples, todo elemento precisa de um mínimo para ao menos existir, e umas dessas propriedades básicas é o `display`, todos os elementos tem algum tipo de `display`, caso contrário ele seria `display:none` e nem na tela ficaria visível pra vc. Como é o casa das tags `<script>` e `<head>` que por default tem o `display` como `none`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui tem uma lista bem legal que vc pode conferir as propriedades padrão de cada elemento: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

Então existem algumas propriedades mínimas, normalmente estabelecidas pelo `user-agent` que são intrínsecas do elemento, para que ele ao menos renderize na tela da forma que diz a especificação e o `box-model`.

Um outro esclarecimento é que quando vc muda o `display` de um elemento ele vai assumir algumas característica mínimas para funcionar. Então quando vc coloca `display:flex` no elemento ele muda de escopo e passa a ser um *`flex-container`*, então tanto ele, quanto os filhos dele passam a assumir características particulares do `flex`. O mesmo acontece com o `display:grid` e `display:table` por exemplo. É um efeito em cascata de pai para filho nesse caso, mas nada impede que vc manipule manualmente esses `displays` descendentes herdados (não que isso seja indicado).

Muito disso é feito para ajudar o usuário a não ter que escrever manualmente cada uma das propriedades de cada um dos elementos HTML, se não fosse isso nem faria sentido vc ter mais de um tipo de elemento, vc simplesmente teria um elemento único para tudo e teria que colocar na mão cada uma das propriedades dele, imagina o quanto isso atrasaria e dificultaria escrever um documento HTML mínimo, ter que colocar `display` na mão em cada elemento que se cria, ter que definir tudo do zero. Não faria o menor sentido para uma linguagem de marcação como se propõem o HTML

Comment: Nesse link do w3schools, alguns valores estão como `internal value`. Isso quer dizer o que? Que é algo que depende da implementação de cada browser?

Comment: @hkotsubo bom observado. Reparei que é só nas cores, não sei se é pq isso fica a cargo do browser, ou das definições do user no OS, como algumas configs de acessibilidade ou algo do tipo. Lá no link não deixa claro do que se trata... :/

Comment: Complementando, achei algo parecido no [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) e no [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html), mas nenhum deles menciona esse `internal value`... Inclusive o WHATWG recomenda cores bem específicas: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#phrasing-content-3

Comment: @hkotsubo vi esse comentário lá na tag `mark`: /* this color is just a suggestion and can be changed based on implementation feedback */
` aparentemente algumas cores ficam a cargo de quem implementa mesmo